# Solving inhomogenous wave equation

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

> Solve the initial value problem:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> v_{tt} = c^2 v_{xx} + x \sin t \ \ &\text{for} \ \ -\infty < x < \infty, t > 0\\
> v(x,0) = v_t(x,0) = 0 \ \ &\text{for} \ \ -\infty < x < \infty
> \end{cases}$$

Attempted solution - We have $$\begin{cases}
v_{tt} - c^2 v_{xx} = x\sin(t) \ \ &\text{for} \ \ -\infty < x < \infty, t > 0\\
v(x,0) = v_t(x,0) = 0 \ \ &\text{for} \ \ -\infty < x < \infty
\end{cases}$$
Let $f(x,t) = x\sin(t)$, $v(x,0) = g(x) = 0$, $v_t(x,0) = h(x) = 0$. Then by d'Alembert's formula and Duhamel's principle gives the solution:
\begin{align*}
v(x,t) &= \frac{1}{2}\left[ g(x + ct) + g(x - ct) \right] + \frac{1}{2c}\int_0^t \left(\int_{x - c(t-s)}^{x + c(t-s)}f(y,s)\,dy\right)\,ds\\
&= 0 + 0 + \frac{1}{2c}\int_0^t \left(\int_{x - c(t-s)}^{x + c(t-s)}y \sin(s)\,d y \right)\,ds\\
&= \frac{1}{2c}\int_0^t \left[ \left.\frac{y^2}{2}\sin(s)\right|_{x - c(t-s)}^{x + c(t-s)} \right]\,ds\\
&= \frac{1}{4c}\int_{0}^{t}\left[ (x+c(t-s))^2 - (x - c(t-s))^2 \right]\sin(s)\,ds\\
&= \frac{1}{4c}\int_0^t (4xct - 4xcs)\sin(s)\,ds\\
&\,\,\, \vdots\\
&= xt - x \sin(t)
\end{align*}
Thus $$v(x,t) = x(t - \sin(t))$$

This is a bit tedious but I wanted to check if my solution is correct. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: How does $s$ appear in your solution when it is a "dummy" integration variable.  Substitute your solution into the PDE and see if it satisfies the PDE subject to the initial conditions.  It won't.

Comment: What is $s$? This looks like a *terrible* mistake, if $s$ is the integration variable. Also, you have lost a $c$ somewhere.

Comment: By the way, an easy and fun way of doing what Mark suggests is using a computer algebra system. In Maple, for example, you only need to type "v:="(your expression); "diff(v, t$2) - c^2*diff(v, x$2) - x*sin(t);" You obtain an expression; simplify it (using the built-it "simplify" command, or by hand) and if it is $0$ the solution was right. Otherwise it was wrong. (Oh, and you should check initial conditions also. The first one looks OK).

Comment: I may have made a few algebra/calc mistakes I will re-edit the solution a little later tonight

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I made some edits if you could take a look

Comment: Well, tell me that you cannot verify for yourself if it is correct or not. You only need to check the initial conditions and then plug the function you found into the equation. It is a matter of computing a couple of easy derivatives.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I did check it, seems correct to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, your result is correct. You already checked this by verifying that the initial conditions are satisfied and then plugging the function you found into the equation.